# Animation from a C++ program

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, visualization

I have a C++ program in Linux which operates on and gives as the result the trajectories of some simple geometric objects in three or two dimensions. I need to visualize the movement of these simple entities and have a video file as an output. How do I do that, what libraries/software do I need for this?

Comment: So you have an existing visualization/3d generation program that you want to add animation capability to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple library for 2D would be [openFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/). It's fast to setup and use. To make your video, you could output the objects on the screen and capture the output with a program like Fraps.
As for 3D, there are is afaik no simple Frameworks that let you get started really fast. One possibility would be [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/), which is relatively easy to use. The other would be, of course, OpenGL but it takes quite some time to get used to a pure graphics library. As for the video again, capture it with e.g. Fraps.